# HTML5 and Cookies

Tags: html, cookies

With the emergence of HTML 5 and various client side storage technologies, do you see any useful need for cookies?  Assume there isn't a requirement to support older browser.

Answer (score 3):

Login validation will still use them. Don't fix what's not broken.

Comment: Local Storage won't work as it is not available from server-side whereas cookies are.

Answer (score 1):

Diodeus is right on—if it ain't broke, why fix it? Cookies are very well supported with many browsers, including older ones, so using cookies would be a more compatible idea than using HTML5 client-side options, as many browsers do not fully support HTML5, and most of the older ones (IE8 and before) likely never will.

Although sessions are a good idea for client-side, cookies are useful for a "remember this user" capability that sessions lack, as sessions disappear after the user closes the window.

Comment: But I don't care about older browsers. Local Web Storage does not disappear after the user closes the window.

Comment: Steve: Only session cookies disappear when the user closes the browser. Normal cookies have an expiry date. And if people use the delete private data functions, html5 storage is deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies will still be around as an option just like Session is still an option for server-side.  In terms of Html5 client side storage options, it's one of the more volatile parts of the specification still.  Many/most browsers are support Html5 to some degree; however, how they are implementing the storage isn't consistent yet since it's changed in the spec a couple times.

To paraphrase Diodeus's answer... Cookies aren't broke so no need to fix or replace them.  Html5 storage is just another option.